# ORA-00911: invalid character exception raised upon inserting records from variables

Tags: oracle, jdbc

```
public class MainApp {
static final String JDBC_DRIVER="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
static final String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost";
static final String USER="system";
static final String PASS="system";

public static void main (String args[])
{
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;

    try{
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        System.out.println("Connecting to Database.....");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        //stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE table Driver (phoneNumber number(10) primary key, licenseNumber number(5),driverName varchar(30),address varchar(10))");



        //stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT into Driver values (9013105837,12347,'sunny','Delhi')");
        String sql;
       sql="SELECT phoneNumber,licenseNumber,driverName,address FROM Driver";


       //insert a new record
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Phone Number:");
       long phone = sc.nextLong();
       System.out.println("License Number:");
       long license=sc.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Name:");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Address:");
        String address = sc.next();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT into `Driver` values ("+phone+"," + license +",'" + name + "','" + address + "')");

       //search by phone number(primary key)
       //search by license number
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            long pn=rs.getLong("phoneNumber");
            long ln=rs.getLong("licenseNumber");
            String dn=rs.getString("driverName");
            String add =rs.getString("address");

            System.out.println("Phone Number:" +pn);
            System.out.println("License Number:" +ln);
            System.out.println("Name:" +dn);
            System.out.println("Address:" +add);
            System.out.println("--end of record--");



        }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();


        }
        catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Done!!");

        }
        }
}
```

**I am able to insert static values with ease,but soon as I try to take the Input from the user,I get an exception.**

```
OUTPUT
Connecting to Database.....
Creating statement...
Phone Number:
9013020737
License Number:
12349
Name:
rohit
Address:
dwarka
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I cannot seem to figure out what invalid character I'm providing. Please help.I'm fairly new to jdbc, so please excuse me if the question seems too basic.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** concatenate values. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead. Also: those dreaded backticks are invalid for Oracle. Get rid of them in your SQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really be using prepareStatement to insert data.  With your existing code, what happens if the user enters O'Reilly into the name input?

Try this instead:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into driver values (?,?,?,?)");
pst.setLong(1,phone);
pst.setLong(2,license);
pst.setString(3,name);
pst.setString(4,address);
pst.executeQuery();
```